# Using ' (' (space followed by parenthesis) as field separator in awk

Tags: regex, awk

In an `awk` script I am trying to use ' (' as the field separator.
However unless I escape the bracket with double back-slash, like this:

```
BEGIN {FS=" \\("}
```

it does not work.

If I use `FS=" \("` I get

```
awk: prog:2: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
awk: prog:2: fatal: :, [., or [=: / (/
```

output and if I don't escape the bracket at all I get just the

`awk: prog:2: fatal: :, [., or [=: / (/` message.

Can you please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

To use `␣(` (space+parenthesis) as field separator in `awk`, use `"␣\\\("`:

```
$ echo "a (b (c" | awk -F " \\\(" '{ print $1; print $2; print $3 }'
a
b
c
```

Alternatively, use single quotes and two backslashes:

```
$ echo "a (b (c" | awk -F ' \\(' '{ print $1; print $2; print $3 }'
a
b
c
```

The reason for this is that `␣(` (a single parenthesis *with* a leading space) is a malformed regular expression. The left parenthesis opens a grouping that is never closed. This is why it needs to be escaped.

The reason that `(` (a single parenthesis *without* a leading space) works is that when `FS` is a single character, it's not treated as a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread when searching for a solution to a similar problem - using `␣` OR `(` as a field separator for awk. This didn't quite answer it, but let me to my solution:

if you want the combination `␣(` as a single unit to separate files in awk, do `awk -F '( \\()' ...`:

```
$ echo "This (maybe) is a test()" | awk -F '( \\()' '{print $1 "\n" $2 "\n" $3 "\n" $4 "\n" $5 "\n" $6 "\n" $7; print "Number of Fields: " NF}'
This
maybe) is a test()





Number of Fields: 2
```

If you're looking for a solution to my similar problem - either `␣` OR `(`, do `awk -F '( |\\()' ...`:

```
$ echo "This (maybe) is a test()" | awk -F '( |\\()' '{print $1 "\n" $2 "\n" $3 "\n" $4 "\n" $5 "\n" $6 "\n" $7; print "Number of Fields: " NF}'
This

maybe)
is
a
test
)
Number of Fields: 7
```